# Setup Clion with boost on windows 7

Tags: windows, boost, cygwin, clion

i need some simple example how to include boost libraries/headers with CMake in Clion IDE under windows 7.
need it for C++ 11.
Boost libs and headers are installed in custom directories.
I have installed cygwin x64 for compiler.

**some solution:**
i just made include of boost headers with cygdrive format

```
include_directories("/cygdrive/e/Libs/BoostLibs/include/boost-1_57")
```

But still dont understand where Clion gets the libs from.

**better solution**
need to set var `BOOST_ROOT`
so i did (and used more variables):

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "/cygdrive/e/Libs/BoostLibs/include/boost-1_57")
```

then it can be found and included

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
ENDIF()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm trying out JetBrains CLion EAP (build 140.1740.3) with Boost framework v1.57.0. I got it to work by adding the below lines to the file "CMakeLists.txt" (which comes by default with a new CLion project).

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:\boost_1_57_0")
set(BOOSTROOT "C:\boost_1_57_0")

find_package(Boost 1.57.0)

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find boost!")
endif()
```

Comment: Does it use the same if I use MSVC as a Compiler?? After I put your code in CMakeList.txt, It built successful but I still cannot include Boost lib.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, CLion doesn't get the libraries. CMake does.

In any case, I was able to solve your problem using this:

```
set(Boost_Path "e:/Libs/BoostLibs/include")
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "${Boost_Path}/boost_1_57_0")
find_package(Boost 1.57.0)
```

Try that and to know if it works, you could use this:

```
message("Boost_INCLUDE_DIR: " ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR })
```

or

```
if(Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "It works!")
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()
```

With the first one you will know if `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` is set correctly, while with the second one you will see the the message only if it found the Boost Library and you will include the directory.

Let me know if it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score -3):

As much as I love CLion, IMO it's better to use [Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/) for development on Windows.  Let Windows be Windows and let Unix be Unix.  Trying to beat one into being the other creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: i use both now, debugging -> VS, fast coding -> CLion.

Comment: That's an interesting combination.  Having used CLion for the past few months, it does feel "faster" to write code in it.  For native C++, the VS experience has been getting more and more sluggish with each release.  I honestly don't know what it is that is at fault.  Sometimes it's an add-on (the boost.test add-on recently made it HORRIBLY slow to just type code, so I had to uninstall it), sometimes it's the core VS stuff.  I turn off as much as possible and still the feeling is sluggish.